# Proving the periodicity of function

Tags: calculus

I just wanted someone to verify the proof i have written

> Problem statement: If $f(x)$ is periodic with period $T$, then $f(ax+b)$ is  periodic with period $T/a$, $a>0$

My procedure:

1) $f(x) = f(x+T)$; (since $f(x)$ is periodic with period $T$)

2) Replacing $x$ by $ax+b$, $f(ax+b)$= $f(ax+b+T)$(since f(x) is periodic with T and this means $T$ being the smallest no. for the repetition of value $f(x)$ ) = $f(a[x+T/a]+b)$

3) 2) shows that $x+T/a$ is the point of repetition of value $f(ax+b)$ for any $x$ belonging to domain  and could be the period of $f(ax+b)$,for $T/a$ really to be the period , it has to be the smallest no. for repetition of $f(ax+b)$

4) Let us assume that a period for $f(ax+b)$ exists $T_1$(say) and $**T_1$<$(T/a)$, then $f(a(x+T_1)+b)$=$f(ax+b)$=$f(ax+aT_1+b)$ (we assumed that $T_1$ is the period)**

5)from 2)  $f(ax+b)$= $f(ax+b+T)$ = $f(ax+aT_1+b)$(from 4) )= $f(ax+(aT_1/T)T+b)$, but  $f(ax+b)= f(ax+b+T)$ shows that $T$ is the period of $f(x)$(see prob. statement and 1) ) thus in $f(ax+(aT_1/T)T+b)$ , since $T$ is the period of $f(x)$, $(aT_1/T) \geq 1$ or $T1 \geq (T/a)$, thus contradicting our assumption $T_1$ as a period and thus $T/a$ is the period of $f(ax+b)$.

Did I do correctly?

Comment: Does "P.T" stand for "prove that"? If so, this is nonstandard notation, and you might as well just write it out.

Comment: yes. it means prove that

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow your step 2 at the end. Maybe you need more parentheses? Why does that equal the previous expression?

---

If $g(x)=f(x+b)$, the graph of $g$ is the graph of $f$ shifted left by $b$ units. So $g$ has the same period as $f$.

If $h(x)=g(ax)$, the graph of $h$ is the graph of $g$ scaled horizontally toward/away from the $y$-axis by a factor of $\frac{1}{a}$. So $h$ has a period that is $\left|\frac{1}{a}\right|$ times the period of $g$.

Hence, the period of $h(x)=g(ax)=f(ax+b)$ is $T\cdot\frac{1}{|a|}$, or just $\frac{T}{|a|}$.

Comment: i mean that a function repeats its value at period "t" or integral multiples of it. since f(x) = f(x+T), thus f(ax+b) = f(ax+b+T) , in the last step, f(ax+b)= f(ax+b+T) = f(ax+aT1+b)= f(ax+{aT1/T}T+b) since we assumed T1 as period ,also f(ax+b) = f(ax+b+nT) where 'n' is an integral multiple of T, comparing f(ax+b+nT) with f(ax+{aT1/T}T+b) ,aT1/T must be ≥ T ie: must be the multiple of T, thus aT1/T ≥T

Comment: It's just that I believe that is not what you wrote above. In your item (2), you say $f(ax+b+T)=f(ax+T/a+b)$.

Comment: I can see now that you used braces when you wrote this. But braces are invisible LaTeX grouping characters, so they need to be escaped if you want to see them in the output. If you want $f(a\{x+T/a\}+b)$, you have to type \{ and \}, not just { and }.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler way would be to say that $f(x) = f(x+T)$, so $f(ax+b) = f(ax+b+T) = f(a(x+\frac{T}{a}) + b)$ which means that the function repeats with period $x+\frac{T}{a}$.

However, it looks as if your method is correct, too. It seems like after 2) you are done (if you mean with parenthesis, $f(a(x+\frac{T}{a})+b)$ and the rest seems to be verification that is indeed the smallest period?

Comment: yes, you're right i was verifying that T/a is indeed the period after 2). did it go well?

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x):=f(ax+b)$.

As$$g(x+\frac Ta)=f(ax+T+b)=f(ax+b)=g(x),$$
the function $g$ has obviously the period $\dfrac Ta$.

Now assume $g$ has a shorter period, let $\dfrac{T'}a$ with $T'<T$. We have

$$f(x+T')=g\left(\frac{x+T'-b}a\right)=g\left(\frac{x-b}a\right)=f(x),$$
so that the period of $f$ is $T'$, a contradiction.

Comment: was my proof correct?

Comment: Why this unfair downvote ?

Comment: i didn't do it , this is the work of somebody else

Comment: @GustavFriedriechWilhelm: I wasn't addressing you in particular.